# Kotlin code with generics to write to MongoDB

Tags: kotlin, generics

In my below class `MongoRepository` I'm trying to write to MongoDB using generics.

```
class MongoRepository<TDataClass : Serializable>(
    connectionString: String,
    dbName: String,
    clazz: Class<TDataClass>
) {
    private val client: CoroutineClient
    private var database: CoroutineDatabase

    init {
        client = KMongo.createClient(
            MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyConnectionString(ConnectionString(connectionString))
                .applyToConnectionPoolSettings {
                    ConnectionPoolSettings.builder().maxConnectionIdleTime(60000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .minSize(5).maxSize(40)
                }
                .build()).coroutine
        database = client.getDatabase(dbName)
    }

    public fun setDatabase(name: String) {
        database = client.getDatabase(name)
    }

    fun write(collectionName: String, data: TDataClass) {
        val collection = database.getCollection(collectionName)
        runBlocking {
            collection?.insertOne(data)
        }
    }
}
```

But the below line of code is throwing error:

```
database.getCollection(collectionName)
```

The error is:

```
Not enough information to infer type variable TDocument
```

Answer (score 0):

`getCollection` is a generic method and needs to know the type it will return. From the [docs of KMongo](https://litote.org/kmongo/quick-start/).

```
val client = KMongo.createClient().coroutine //use coroutine extension
val database = client.getDatabase("test") //normal java driver usage
val col = database.getCollection<Jedi>() //KMongo extension method
```

The 3rd line specifies what is the type that `getCollection` will return.

In your case I think this will fix your code:

```
val collection = database.getCollection<TDataClass>(collectionName)
```

Comment: When we provide the actual class name like "Jedi" it will work. But when you pass a generics name, it won't compile. Please run the code that I pasted and you can see the error